# Specify SNI server_hostname when performing request with asyncio/aiohttp

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp, sni, sslcontext

Hello fellow developers ! I'm stuck in a corner case and I'm starting to be out of hairs to pull... Here is the plot :

```
            load-balancer.example.com:443 (TCP passthrough)
                               /\
                              /  \
                             /    \
                            /      \
          s1.example.com:443        s2.example.com:443
              (SSL/SNI)                  (SSL/SNI)
```

The goal is to stress-test the upstreams `s1` and `s2` directly using `aiohttp` with certificate-validation enable. Since the load-balancer does not belong to me I don't want to do the stress-test over it.

- the code is not supposed to run on other platforms than GNU Linux with at least Python-v3.7 (but I can use any recent version if needed)
- all servers serve a valid certificate for `load-balancer.example.com`
- `openssl` validates the certificate from the upstreams when using `openssl s_connect s1.example.com:443 -servername load-balancer.example.com`
- `cURL` needs `curl 'https://load-balancer.example.com/' --resolve s1.example.com:443:load-balancer.example.com` and also validates successfully

I am able to launch a huge batch of async `ClientSession.get` requests on both upstreams in parallel but for each request I need to somehow tell `asyncio` or `aiohttp` to use `load-balancer.example.com` as `server_hostname`, otherwise the SSL handshake fails.

Is there an easy way to setup the `ClientSession` to use a specific `server_hostname` when setting up the SSL socket ?
Does someone have already done something like that ?

EDIT : here is the most simple snippet with just a single request :

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio


async def main_async(host, port, uri, params=[], headers={}, sni_hostname=None):
    if sni_hostname is not None:
        print('Setting SNI server_name field ')
        #
        # THIS IS WHERE I DON'T KNOW HOW TO TELL aiohttp
        # TO SET THE server_name FIELD TO sni_hostname
        # IN THE SSL SOCKET BEFORE PERFORMING THE SSL HANDSHAKE
        #
    try:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(raise_for_status=True) as session:
            async with session.get(f'https://{host}:{port}/{uri}', params=params, headers=headers) as r:
                body = await r.read()
                print(body)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Exception while requesting ({e}) ')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main_async(host='s1.example.com', port=443,
                           uri='/api/some/endpoint',
                           params={'apikey': '0123456789'},
                           headers={'Host': 'load-balancer.example.com'},
                           sni_hostname='load-balancer.example.com'))
```

When running it with real hosts, it throws

```py
Cannot connect to host s1.example.com:443 ssl:True 
[SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] '
certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1131)')])
```

Note that the error `certificate has expired` indicates that the certificate proposed to the client is the default certificate since the SNI hostname is `s1.example.com` which is unknow by the webserver running there.

When running it against the load-balancer it works just fine, the SSL handshake happens with the upstreams which serve the certificate and everything is valid.

Also note that

- [`sni_callback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.sni_callback) does not help since it is called after the handshake has started and the certificate was received (and at this point `server_hostname` is a read-only property anyway)
- it does not seem to be possible to set `server_hostname` when creating an `SSLContext` allthough [SSLContext.wrap_socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.wrap_socket) does support `server_hostname` but I was not able to make that work

I hope someone knows how to fill the comment block in that snippet ;-]

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the delayed response, but I recently grappled with the same challenge. To my knowledge, neither the popular asynchronous HTTP library `aiohttp` nor any other contemporary asynchronous HTTP libraries natively support defining the SNI (Server Name Indication) field. To circumvent this limitation, I successfully employed the `urllib3` library and implemented a workaround similar to the one you've provided:

```py
sni_proxy_ip_addr = "127.0.0.1"  # your SNI proxy server
server_hostname: str = "ifconfig.co"
server_hostname_uri: str = "/json"

pool = urllib3.HTTPSConnectionPool(
    sni_proxy_ip_addr,
    port=443,
    server_hostname=server_hostname
)

try:
    resp = pool.request(
        "GET",
        server_hostname_uri,
        headers={"Host": server_hostname},
        assert_same_host=False,
        retries=False
    )
except urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
    return {'original_ip_addr': sni_proxy_ip_addr}
except urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError:
    return {'original_ip_addr': sni_proxy_ip_addr}
```

PS. google bard is amazing to rewrite your response in more formal ways :)))))